# Python shrink/subtract generator/iterator legth/size

Tags: python

What I want is:

```
num_users = 10
long_generator = (x for x in range(num_users))
short_generator = long_generator[:-1]  # (Wrong syntax, not subscriptable)
```

So the goal is to make `StopIteration` a bit closer.

I know that I can create new generator from the old one but it's not reflecting my intentions in the code:)
I know that generator has pretty specific implementation and may exists some technical restrictions, but anyway...

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish. What, exactly, is the behavior you expect with `generator_with_me = generator_with_me[:-1]`? It looks like you want a new generator with everything but the last element. The only way to do that is to *consume the generator* into, say, a list then remove the last element

Comment: If you want to index it, you have to turn it into an indexable container, like a list or tuple.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools`, there might be something there that you can use.

Comment: @Barmar `itertools.islice`, which would be the closest thing, doesn't support what the OP wants (since you cannot really do it without consuming the *whole iterator*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`more-itertools.islice_extended`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.islice_extended) supports negative stop indices.

```
>>> from more_itertools import islice_extended
>>> g = (x for x in 'banana')
>>> list(islice_extended(g, 0, -1))
['b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n']
```

It works by [caching `-stop` items in a `deque`](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/v8.14.0/more_itertools/more.py#L2496-L2498).

Comment: How is this actually implemented? It has to consume the whole iterator and store everything but the last item, no?

Comment: If the stop index is `-k`, you would only need to store `O(k)` items.

Comment: @chepner yes, what I meant by "everything" was "everything included in the slice"

Comment: Stopping early without consuming the underlying iterator sounds like a more difficult variation of the halting problem.